# First Interview With The CTO

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, junior

I have applied in a growing start-up for junior Software Engineer position, after recruiters screening via skype I was given two tests on codility.

Each of which I have completed with 100% correctness, and right after two days, I was asked for an interview with the CTO for 30 min over the phone. And if qualified I will spent a day in the company with the employees according to the recruiter.

Any suggestions about what kind of questions I should be expecting, will it be more technical or behavioral type interview?

Is it a common practice to have Junior Engineers to be interviewed by the CTO?

Comment: Is it common practice for That Many Capital Letters?

Comment: i am sorry, If Capital Letters Upsets you :D

Comment: Excessive use of capital letters in English makes you appear to be a teenager. It's a bad practice, especially in business communication. Break that habit if you want native speakers of English to take you seriously.

Comment: @keshlam Non-native English speakers (such as me) won't take it seriously either in professional communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good CTO would be concerned with the culture and performance of their development team, and when I have interviewed with startups I have met their CEO/CTO/CIOs. I personally would be more concerned if the CTO was not interested in meeting new hires in their team.

From my experiences, phone interviews are more likely to contain behavioural interview questions than technical interview questions and face-to-face interviews are more likely to have technical interview questions than behavioural interview questions. So it's a great idea to prepare for both: try to find out about the technologies they use and refresh your foundation computer science skills.

Good luck with the interview :-).